# Signature mismatch. Authorization signature or client credential is wrong

Tags: here-api

Using the following code to try and create the signature and get the bearer token.

```
<?php
$tm=time();

$param_str = "grant_type=client_credentials&oauth_consumer_key=xxxx&oauth_nonce=xxx&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256&oauth_timestamp=".$tm."&oauth_version=1.0";

//die($param_str);
$base_str = "POST&" .urlencode("https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token") . "&" . urlencode($param_str);
//die($base_str);
$sign_key = urlencode("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")."&";

$signature= hash_hmac("sha256",$base_str,$sign_key);

$url = "https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token";

$ch = curl_init( $url );

$headers = [
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xxx",oauth_nonce="xxx",oauth_signature="'.$signature.'",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="'.$tm.'",oauth_version="1.0"',
    'Cache-Control: no-cache'
];

$payload="grant_type=client_credentials";
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
# Return response instead of printing.
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
# Send request.
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Tried various combinations. Getting the same error (Signature mismatch. Authorization signature or client credential is wrong). Even tried copying the exact url encoded string from the document, replacing relevant information and still not working. Is there something I am not understanding at all from the documentation or something I am missing here in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for signature mismatch is that the one you created is different than the one server created. Check the following –

- Did you convert the signing key and base string into bytes before
  passing it to HMAC-SHA256 hashing algorithm.
- Did you convert the    output of HMAC-SHA256 hashing algorithm into
  base64 string.

also check this [link](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client/tree/master/src) if this can help you.